# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtf' ... verified installed in virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

My import statements are as follows:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
```

I am able to execute the file - blank.py - within Pycharm and do not receive a ModuleNotFoundError.

Whenever I execute `flask run` in terminal I get `ModuleNotFoundError:  'flask_wtf'` and it traces back to 'blank.py'.

I am not sure why this is happening as I have both flask and flask-wtf installed globally and locally. I have never had this problem when working with other libraries.

How do I fix this? Thank you for you help.

Comment: got the same error

Comment: I ended up making a new project in Pycharm and it worked okay. I wasn't able to trace the issue.